# Changing the label of chart

Tags: javascript, html, angular, chart.js, ngx-translate

Is it possible to change the labels of the chart in html.

I have implemented a doughnut chart.
the labels are defined as

```
public chartLabels = ["korea", "tokyo", "sydney"]
```

I understand I can change the label names here.

but I have to name it in such a way that the label translates depending on the language selection. 
 I do it in html like

```
{{'KOREA'|translate}}
```

So how do I change labels for the translation needs

the labels in html are defined so

```
 <canvas baseChart
      [labels]="chartLabels"     
      chartType="pie">
 </canvas>
```

Comment: Which translation library are you using?

Comment: it is ngx-translate/core

Comment: You can get your string translations for those labels in your TypeScript code by injecting the `TranslateService` service in your constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use something like this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
       <canvas baseChart
          [labels]="chartLabels"     
          chartType="pie">
      </canvas>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {};

    chartLabels = ["korea", "tokyo", "sydney"]
    translatedChartLabels = []

    ngOnInit() {
        this.translate.get(this.chartLabels)
            .subscribe(translations => {
                /* translations is now an object with { 
                 "key1": "translated value", 
                 "key1": "translated value" } 
                 and needs to be converted to an array again. */
                this.translatedChartLabels = Object.values(translations)
        });
    }
}
```

```
 <canvas baseChart
      [labels]="translatedChartLabels"     
      chartType="pie">
 </canvas>
```

Comment: I used  
this.chartLabels[0]= this.translate.instant('LABEL_KOREA')

Comment: this.chartLabels[1]= this.translate.instant('LABEL_TOKYO')

Comment: this.chartLabels[2]= this.translate.instant('LABEL_SYDNEY')

Comment: but it translates only after the page is refereshed

Comment: You should not use `instant`. The docs (https://github.com/ngx-translate/core)  says:
instant(key: string|Array<string>, interpolateParams?: Object): string|Object: Gets the instant translated value of a key (or an array of keys). /!\ This method is synchronous and the default file loader is asynchronous. You are responsible for knowing when your translations have been loaded and it is safe to use this method. If you are not sure then you should use the get method instead.

Subscribe with `get` instead. The translations will be updated dynamically without the need of a page reload. :)

Comment: how do i use get for an array

Comment: I tried this `ngOnInit(){
    this.translate
      .get(['LABEL_KOREA','LABEL_TOKYO','LABEL_SYDNEY'])
      .subscribe((translations: {[key: string]: string}) => {
        console.log(translations);
      })`
    `this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe(() => {
      this.chartLabels[0]= this.translate.instant('LABEL_KOREA')
      this.chartLabels[1]= this.translate.instant('LABEL_TOKYO')
      this.chartLabels[2]= this.translate.instant('LABEL_SYDNEY')
    })
  }`still it doesnt change without loading

Comment: As I mentioned, you can ***not*** use this.translate.***instant***('LABEL_KOREA'). You have to use ***get***
I've updated my answer to include a suggestion for handeling arrays

Comment: still its the same condition `ngOnInit(){
    this.translate
      .get(this.chartLabels)
      .subscribe((translations: {[key: string]: string}) => {
        console.log(translations);
        this.translatedChartLabels = Object.values(translations)
      })
  }`

Comment: Have you uppercased the strings in the array (if they are uppercased in your translation en.json etc file)? What dose translations log?

Comment: translation log is `LABEL_KOREA: "korea"
LABEL_TOKYO: "tokyo"
LABEL_SYDNEY: "sydney"`