# ERROR TypeError: labels.slice is not a function barChartLabels graph using @ngx-translate Angular

Tags: angular, charts, label, translate

I want to translate barChartLabels when use @ngx-translate Angular.

I have this code that show an error.

In en.json I add this part of code:

```
{ .....
 "waiting-approval": "Waiting Approval",
  "barChartLabels": {
    "initiated": "Initiated",
    "in-progress": "In Progress",
    "completed": "Completed",
    "not-possible": "Not Possible"
  }
 }
}
```

In .ts component I have this code:

```
 (response: any) => {
        console.log('responese compaints', response) 
        this.barChartLabels = response.bar_labels;
        this.barChartData = response.data;
      }
```

and get

```
["initiated", "in-progress", "completed", "not-possible"]
```

in .html code

I have

```
 <canvas baseChart [datasets]="barChartData" [labels]="'barChartLabels' | translate"
                [options]="barChartOptions" [plugins]="barChartPlugins" [legend]="barChartLegend"
                [chartType]="barChartType">
 </canvas>
```

Can you ask me any idea how to translate please?

Update [image] `console.log('responese compaints', response)`

Comment: What is the output of  'console.log('responese compaints', response)' ?

Comment: This is output  `["initiated", "in-progress", "completed", "not-possible"]`

Comment: the [labels] take only array. Try 
`this.barChartLabels = response` and in html replace `[labels]="barChartLabels"` delete the tick

Comment: Sorry I update `console.log('responese compaints', response)`

Comment: Ok, try in html `[labels]="barChartLabels | translate"`. and the ts is the same of yours.

Comment: Show error: `ERROR TypeError: labels.slice is not a function
    at ChartElement.buildTicks (Chart.js:12591)` and `core.js:4352 ERROR TypeError: this.labels.filter is not a function
    at BaseChartDirective.ngDoCheck (ng2-charts.js:430)`

Comment: And when I try `[labels]="'barChartLabels' | translate"` it doesn't show

Comment: OK try to use `import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';` as service https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56046229/changing-the-label-of-chart.

Comment: I am using this plugin import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230538/discussion-between-antonio-esposito-and-a-b).

Answer (score -1):

Import

`import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';`

Inject service

`constructor(private translateService: TranslateService){}`

And

`this.translateService.instant('something.else')`

Comment: I try to use `this.translate.get('barChartLabels', { user: this.chartLabels }).subscribe((text: string) => { console.log('text', text) });` but how to display in .html, so how to call in [labels] ?

Comment: What is the output of console?

Comment: `{initiated: "Initiated", in-progress: "In Progress", completed: "Completed", not-possible: "Not Possible"}` when change language in other, make refresh page and in console show other language `{initiated: "xxxx", in-progress: "yyyy", completed: "eeee", not-possible: "gggg"}`

Comment: Object.values(text) can help you?

Comment: I change like this `this.translatedChartLabels = Object.values(this.translate.instant('barChartLabels'))` only the problem is: [labels] don't change when I select language.When I select language in console show correct, when I refresh page show correct and in labels.When I select other language in console doesn't show nothing, when I refresh page data show correct in console and in labels. Translate make only when  refresh page

Comment: You have to use **get** for subscription and then replace the default array with the array of other languange.
`this.translate.get('barChartLabels', { user: this.chartLabels }).subscribe((text: string) => { 
  this.barChartLabels = Object.values(text);  
});`

Comment: I have tried and with get, but doesn't work. Only when I refresh page change labels